# Calculation problem of a complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the integration $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx$$

Consider following integration $$\int_C\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}dz$$

Take the path C as $-X$ to $-\epsilon$, $\Gamma_{\epsilon}$, $\epsilon$ to $X$, $X$ to $X+2i$, $X+2i$ to $\epsilon+2i$, $\Gamma_{\epsilon}'$, $-\epsilon+2i$ to $-X+2i$，$-X+2i$ to $-X$, where $\Gamma_{\epsilon}$ and $\Gamma_{\epsilon}'$ are half circles around $0$ and $2i$ respectively.

Then $$\int_C\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}dz=Res(f(z),i)=2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z(z-i)}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}=-2\pi lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z-i}{e^{-\pi (z-i)}-e^{\pi (z-i)}}=1$$

Moreover $$\mid\int_{X}^{X+2i}\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}dz\mid\leq\int_{X}^{X+2i}\mid\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}\mid dz\leq\int_{X}^{X+2i}\frac{2\sqrt{X^2+4}}{e^{\pi X}} dz=\frac{4\sqrt{X^2+4}}{e^{\pi X}}\rightarrow 0(X\rightarrow \infty)$$.
We can also get that $\int_{-X+2i}^{-X}\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}dz\rightarrow 0(X\rightarrow \infty)$.

$$\mid\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}dz\mid\leq\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi\epsilon}dz=\epsilon/2\rightarrow 0(z\rightarrow 0)$$. By the same reason, we have $$\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-e^{-\pi z}}dz\rightarrow 0(\epsilon\rightarrow 0)$$.

Then we would get that $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_{\infty}^0\frac{x+2i}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_0^{-\infty}\frac{x+2i}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx=1$$.

But $$\int_{\infty}^0\frac{2i}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_0^{-\infty}\frac{2i}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx=\int_{\infty}^0\frac{2i}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}+\frac{2i}{e^{-\pi x}-e^{\pi x}}dx=0$$.

And $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_{\infty}^0\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx+\int_0^{-\infty}\frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}dx=0$$ obviously.

So where is the problem of my calculation?

Comment: Your function has two singularities inside of $C$, namely $i$ and $2i$. You just considered $i$ but not $2i$.

Comment: @Mundron Schmidt, $2i$ is excluded by $\Gamma_{\epsilon}'$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I know it's the right answer. Can you give me your details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{\pi  x}-e^{-\pi  x}=\sinh \pi x$

$\sinh \pi x=0$ when $x=ki,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$$2I=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x}{2 \sinh (\pi  x)} \, dx=2 \pi  i \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \text{Res}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sinh (\pi  x)},\{x, ki\}\right)=2 \pi  i \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{i (-1)^n n}{2 \pi }$$
The generating function of $(-1)^n n$ is $g(z)=-\dfrac{z}{(z+1)^2}$

Thus we have $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n n=g(1)=-\frac14$$
and 
$$2I=\frac14\to I=\frac18$$

Comment: Hm, this approach gives the right answer, though it has several problems. Likely, you chose to use a semicircle contour in the upper half of the complex plane.  Note that this diverges as $x\to i\infty$.  And we see this divergence in the resulting sum of residues.  :-/

Answer (score 2):

Here lies the real approach.

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\infty\frac x{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac{xe^{-\pi x}}{1-e^{-2\pi x}}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty xe^{-(2n+1)\pi x}~\mathrm dx\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty xe^{-(2n+1)\pi x}~\mathrm dx\\&=\frac1{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}~\mathrm dx\\&=\frac1{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}\\&=\frac1{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(2n)^2}\\&=\frac3{(2\pi)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\\&=\frac18\end{align}$$

Comment: Pretty Good. But this is a problem of a textbook of complex analysis. So I want to solve it by complex approach.

Comment: Yep, I would suspect as much.  Unfortunately, I am not as much so magic fingers with CA as I'd like to be, so... I'll see if I can cook up something later

Comment: I have no fingers at all with CA. There is another way to the solution computing the antiderivative and get something involving polylogarithms. Your solution is nice and simple.